# What "Symbol" means in jcmd VM.native_memory summary?

Tags: java, memory

`jcmd VM.native_memory summary` contains memory usage of different parts of JVM, and most of those sections are obvious - except `Symbol`:

```
                Symbol (reserved=11091KB, committed=11091KB)
                       (malloc=9357KB #87026) 
                       (arena=1734KB #1)
```

I was not able to find description of this anywhere - what is this?